# Is every killed Markov process still a Markov process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Suppose we've got $X=(X(t))_{t\geq 0}$. $X$ is a strong Markov process with respect to filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, taking values in some subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We take $\tau$ - a stopping time w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_t$ and we kill $X$ in $\tau$ obtaining new process $Y$ which is given by

$$
Y(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 X(t), & \textrm{ for }  t<\tau\\
 \Delta, & \textrm{ for } t\geq \tau
\end{array}
\right..
$$
where $\Delta$ is an isolated point.

We can then ask if $Y$ is still strong Markov process. There are a lot examples when it is (e.g. when $\tau$ is terminal time) however I am interested in an example when *it isn't*. I've got simple examples when killing destroys some other properties (e.g time-homogenity) but Markov property seems not so easy to eliminate.

I would be very thankful for any ideas.

Comment: Try a stopping time that depends on the path of $X$ and not just its current state (like the 2nd hitting time of $0$ for a random walk).

Comment: I think that it is always true for a continuous time Markov chain (assuming that paths are right continuous).

Comment: @angry_pacifist: Obviously not, by the previous comment.